# Delegated click event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, events

I am developing a web application. You can find the website [here](http://terkep.trisztan.hu).

If you click on the "road" icon, and after the menu opened the plus sign ("+"), a text input will appear with a label. This `<ul>` is using the [jQueryUI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) plugin, to - of course - be able to sort the addresses after input.

[image: The address fields]

I would like to add a click event to the label of these address fields, so that when a user clicks the number, a dialog box will appear where he/she can manually edit the number (it can get a little counter-productive if there are hundreds of addresses).

Since the `<li>` elements, in which the label and the inputs are gets created later, I tried to delegate the click event, like so:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.control-label', function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

However the event never fires. I am starting to think that maybe the sortable plugin disables my events to that label?

Here is the HTML code of an address field (label+input+delete button)

```
<li>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">1.</label>
        <div class="col-md-11 input-group">
            <input type="text" name="waypoints[]" class="form-control form-control-square waypoint animated fadeInRight" placeholder="Megálló" autocomplete="off" required=""><span class="input-group-btn animated fadeInRight"><button type="button" class="btn btn-square btn-danger btn-removewaypoint animated fadeInRight">×</button></span>
            <div class="search-suggestions">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/oeh242wp/) is the addWaypoint() function which adds a new row. This gets called every time when the user clicks the + button.

Edit: Apparently it isnt the sortable plugin, but something else that blocks the click event. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: [This may be related?](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-the-same-element-have-draggable-and-click-event)

Comment: I just tested that in jsfiddle and it works. must be something else  disabling the click event

Comment: @RiceJunkie I know that there is a way in Chrome's developer console to see what events are attached to an element, but I don't know how to check that. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can select your element in developer tool and on the right hand side where your css styles are listed there is a tab for event listeners

Comment: @TrisztánThar I've already checked that - you can just see jQuery has attached itself at the various points.  Which makes sense - you haven't attached your code directly to `click`, just asked jQuery to invoke your function when the event happens.  I'm trying to repro the actual issue on jsfiddle at the moment...

Comment: That click handler seems to be attached to `.button.fadeInRight` -- the red x ... or could that be a separate handler?

Comment: FYI [this is what](http://jsfiddle.net/9ahenwtq/) I have so far.  Has a `sortable` with elements that exist on page load, adds the event handler, more elements then added.  You can click on the X on any of them and the alert pops up, and they're all sortable.  Think you may need to try to simplify what's happening on your page until you can isolate what's causing it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes. I tried to not delegate, but simply use .on('click') directly on the element, but it doesn't work either. Peter, I've added the HTML code of a "row" of address field. Indeed, there is a click event attached to the red x, but that's another event. I need to have a click event fire when the user clicks the _number_.

Comment: Just to cover off a point that your last comment raised - just [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ahenwtq/1/) to have the sortable use the use the label as the handle - still the same behaviour.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the label isn't the handle. I'm attaching the .sortable() event when the <li> element gets created, when you click the "+" button to add another row. Here is that function: http://jsfiddle.net/oeh242wp/

Comment: Ah, so .sortable() is being called multiple times - in theory you only need to call it once.  Wonder if that's having an effect also.  Sadly laptop battery has now died, so not in a position to try anything anymore!  I'll look back tomorrow, see if there's any answers yet...!

Comment: Yes, since I'm not calling sortable on individual <li> elements, but on the whole <ul>, so when a new <li> element gets added, I have to call .sortable() again to have that new element included too.

Comment: I'm not sure you do - see my jsfiddle again.  `sortable` is only called once, then more elements added without ever calling it again

Answer (score -2):

You need to setup a variable related to each control-label class in order to console.log it (or alert it, or use it anyway you want).

This is how I suggest you modify the javascript:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.conrtol-label', function () {
    var spanText=$(this).text();
    console.log($(this));
    alert(spanText);
});
```

Maybe this fiddle would help: http://jsfiddle.net/jo6957au/1/

Modified to use li's http://jsfiddle.net/jo6957au/3/

Comment: The OP said the event isn't firing in the first place - how is this going to help get the event firing?